# Getting array of related IDs from a belongsToMany relation - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I had [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-get-relations-id-belongstomany) solution working well in Laravel 5.3

```
$procedure = Procedure::findOrFail($id);
$attached_stages = $procedure->stages()->getRelatedIds()->toArray();
```

In my `Procedure` model:

```
public function stages()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Stage', 'procedure_stage', 'procedure_id', 'stage_id')->withPivot('id','status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now, after migrating to Laravel 5.4, I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRelatedIds()
```

Seems that the `getRelatedIds` has been removed.

#### My question:

how to get the array in 5.4?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: getRelatedIds() is changed to allRelatedIds(). Hope People will fix their errors in future

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to get ids array you can use pluck function

```
$procedure->stages()->pluck('stages.id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Your solution works. You might upgrade the answer by adding table name for the pludked ids: ``->pluck('stages.id')`

Answer (score 15):

It was removed(basically, changed the name, nothing more) from 5.4, but you have it in another name as i looked deep inside the `belongToMany.php` file. Use this
And it should work very nicely.

```
$attached_stages = $procedure->stages()->allRelatedIds()->toArray();
```

Hope this help you, and other who will face that problem in the future and look in this post.

Comment: This helped me when I added a global scope to a model based on a user's relationships with that model. Doing (for example) `$procedure->stages()->pluck('id')` with the global scope on the Stages model would result in a recursive global scope, but this solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible it will be useful for users on Laravel 5.1:

```php
$procedure->stages()->getQuery()->lists('stage_id')->toArray();
```

or

```php
$procedure->stages()->getQuery()->pluck('stage_id')->toArray();
```

It is IDE friendly code version. :)